# Preselecting an active radiolist in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am using an activeradiolist in my form and I would like to have the first item selected, but this fails

This is the radiolist:

```
 <?=Html::activeRadioList($model, is_normal, [1 => 'Customer truck', 2 => 'Transporter truck '])?>
```

I have tried:

```
  <?=
   $model->is_normal = 1;
Html::activeRadioList($model, is_normal, [1 => 'Customer truck', 2 => 'Transporter truck '])?>
```

The above hides the radiolist and displays 1 on the screen.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are echoing the `1`.

`<?=` is short for `<?php echo`.

Change the code to:

```
<?php
$model->is_normal = 1;
echo Html::activeRadioList($model, 'is_normal', [1 => 'Customer truck', 2 => 'Transporter truck ']);
?>
```

Comment: Could you check on this one please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014565/defining-the-url-in-yii-ajax-get