# Defining the url in yii ajax get

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii, yii2

Am trying to perform an ajax get to a yii2 controller but the link fails to pass correctly

This is what i have tried:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl. "/checks/items" ?>',  //this fails
   type: 'get',
   data: {
             category:category,
             _csrf : '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'
         },
   success: function (data) {
                var parsedResult = $.parseJSON(data);
      .....
   $("#labels_trackcenter").html(html);
   }
  });
```

How do i pass that url

These are the config url rules:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
```

Comment: Where is this code added? In view `*.php` file or `*.js`?

Comment: In the .php file in a script

Comment: Tried `Url::to(['checks/items'])`  ? [Example](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/665/overcoming-removal-of-client-helpers-e-g-ajaxlink-and-clientscript-in-yii-2-0/)

Comment: #insane skull it returns an error of  Unexpected token :  when i use it like   {{{{      url:Url::to(['checks/items']),     }}}}

Comment: solve syntax errors : `url: '".Url::to(['/checks/items'])."',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,take care of concatenation.

```
       $this->registerJs("
        $.ajax({
        url: '" . yii\helpers\Url::to(["/checks/items"]) . "',
        //OR
        url: '" . Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl."/checks/items',

        type: get,
        data: {
                  category:category,
                  _csrf : '" . Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken() . "'
              },
        success: function (data) {
                     var parsedResult = $.parseJSON(data);
                      .....
                     $("#labels_trackcenter").html(html);
        }
      });
   ");
```

Comment: Now am getting an error of MLHttpRequest cannot load yiihelpersurl::to(["checks/items"]). Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Url helper class, it will change your url based on url rules which is configured in web.php file.

```
$.ajax({ 
   //use Url helper class for ajax url 
   url: "<?= yii\helpers\Url::to(['@web/checks/items'],true) ?>", 
   type: 'get', 
   data: { 
     category:category, 
     _csrf : "<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" 
   }, 
   success: function (data) { 
     var parsedResult = $.parseJSON(data); 
     ..... 
     $("#labels_trackcenter").html(html); 
   } 
});
```

Comment: it fails it returns n error:{{http://127.0.0.1/admin/fiona/checks/%3C?php%20echo%20yiihelpersUrl::to([%27…20true)%20?%3E&category=2&_csrf=%3C%3F%3DYii%3A%3A-%3EgetCsrfToken()%3F%3E 404 (Not Found)}}

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI which is you are using, yii2 basic or yii2 advance?

Comment: Am using yii2 advanced

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI Thanks for providing info. Can you add your config file url rules in your question? This will help to find the issue.

Comment: I have added the config url rules

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI as per your url config, you are not using any url rules for the application. Did you tried that url in browser manually also enable yii debug and check the in this url for your project {your-localhost-domainname}/debug/default/index

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> Url::toRoute

```
$.ajax({
   url: '<?php echo Url::toRoute('checks/items'); ?>',  
   type: 'get',
   data: {
             category:category,
             _csrf : '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'
         },
   success: function (data) {
                var parsedResult = $.parseJSON(data);
      .....
   $("#labels_trackcenter").html(html);
   }
  });
```

Comment: url: '<?php echo Url::toRoute('checks/items'); ?>',     fails i have tried  also   url: '<?php echo Url::toRoute("checks/items"); ?>',  which also fails to work. Ajax picks up the <?php tags as a url

Comment: as you are adding your code on php file and using yii2 advance template, you dont need to add php tag. refer my answer. You just need to register your js code using yii2 syntax i .e inside $this->registerJs() method

Answer (score 0):

incase of External Js

Specify Url in the form

```
<form action="<?php echo Url::toRoute('participant-prod/pull-live-data'); ?>" method="get" id="pull-part-data-form">
```

Call Url in the JS file

```
$("#pull-part-data-form").submit((e) => {
e.preventDefault();
let targetUrl = $("#pull-part-data-form").attr('action');
$.ajax({
    url: targetUrl,
    method: 'get',
    data: $("#pull-part-data-form").serializeArray(),
    success: function (response) {
        
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
});
```

})